# To prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{{1}\over {k}} \ge \log n$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

To  show  that  the  series   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {{1}\over {k}}$ diverges ; I have  to  prove  that $${\sum_{k=1}^{n}}{{1}\over{k}} \ge {\log n}$$ The  given  hint  is  that $${{1}\over {k}}\ge \int_k^{k+1}  {1\over x} dx$$

Now,evaluating the RHS, say  $$L=\int_k^{k+1}  {1\over x} dx\\=\log(k+1)-\log\ k\\=\log(1+{1\over k})\\={1\over k}-{1\over{2k^2}}+{1\over {3k^3}}-......$$
How  can I tell  this  is  $L \le {1\over k}?$

If this part is proved then  I guess  the  following  is  like  **:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k}\ge\int_1^2{1\over x}dx +\int_2^3{1\over x}dx +....\int_n^{n+1} {1\over x} dx = \int_1^{n+1} {1\over x} dx=log(n+1)$$

How to  reach  the  conclusion $?$ . This is  going  nowhere .

Comment: Most easily, use that $\frac{1}{x} \leqslant \frac{1}{k}$ for $x \geqslant k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Where $?$

Comment: $$\int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x}\,dx \leqslant \int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{k}\,dx = \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: See also [Showing that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \geq \log{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701050) and [Showing inequality for harmonic series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156326).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\frac 1k&\geq\int_k^{k+1} \frac 1xdx\\
\text{Sum from $k=1$ to $n$:}&\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k&\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}\frac 1xdx=\int_1^{n+1}\frac 1xdx=\log(n+1)\geq\log n \\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k&\geq\log n\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: ok. So  when I  take  $lim\ \  n\rightarrow \infty $  ,  on  the  right  I  get  $log \infty $ which  is  strictly  positive.

Comment: Yes, $\log n \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. So with this you can conclude that the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the telescopic nature of the expression $\log(k+1)-\log(k)$.

For example when $n=3$, you have shown that

$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \geq \log(2)-\log(1)+\log(3)-\log(2)+\log(4)-\log(3) = \log(4)-\log(1)$.

Take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and observe the expression on the right hand side of the inequality.

Comment: I can't see  anything

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $k \leq x \leq k+1$ thus $\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{k}$.

$$L=\int_k^{k+1}  {1\over x} dx \leq \int_k^{k+1}  {1\over k} dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)=n $$
hence by taking logs and exploiting $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for $|x|<1$ we have:
$$ \log(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} $$
so $H_n>\log(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The map $x \mapsto 1/x$ is stricly decreasing and the map $\log$ is strictly increasing , implying that for every $n \geq 1$ we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \geq \int_{x = 1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x} = \log (n+1) > \log (n).
$$