# Prove that $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \geq c\space \log n$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Find $c > 0$ such that for any positive integer $n$, $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \geq  c \log n.$$ As I am now confused with the question written here [Showing that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \geq \log{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701050/showing-that-sum-i-1n-frac1i-geq-logn?rq=1) 
, could anyone give me a hint about the proof?

Comment: what $c$ is that?

Comment: @RSerrao  a constant.

Comment: You're asking why you're asking this question, and not another one? Seriously?

Comment: So Sorry I got it @ProfessorVector. but because the constant in my problem the condition on it is $c > 0$ only so that the other inequality may not be satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that for any positive integer $k$,
$$\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)=\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x}\, dx\leq \frac{1}{k}.$$
Then 
$$\ln(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k))\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: I do not know how to use your hint.

Comment: See my edited answer. Which constant $c$ are you going to choose?

Comment: the constant c = 1

Comment: @weakmathematician Yes, actually any $c\in (0,1]$ is fine.

Comment: @weakmathematician Please edit your question and improve it. Say something like "Find $c>0$ such that for any positive integer $n$..."

Comment: okay I will do :)

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\log(1+x)\leq x$, hence
$$ H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\color{red}{\geq} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\log(k+1)-\log k\right] = \log(n+1).$$
We also have $x\leq \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$, from which:
$$ H_n \leq 1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\right]\color{red}{\leq }\log(n+1)+\left(1-\frac{\log 2}{2}\right)$$
for any $n\geq 2$.